# Ruby Tmail error: undefined symbol: rb_get_kcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tmail

ruby: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/ext/tmailscanner/tmail/tmailscanner.so: undefined symbol: rb_get_kcode

strange error that crash app. 
ruby 1.9.1
rails 2.3.8
tmail 1.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just frozen tmail in rails vendor folder and additionally gem installed tmail.
to resolve this problem I just need to "gem uninstall tmail"

Comment: I'm having the same problem without rails installed. Odd.

Answer (score 2):

Same here, tmail still not compatible with latest MRI 1.9.2, and I don't think it will be updated since everybody should now use the new gem "mail".

FYI, back to tmail-1.2.0, I only get warnings and things seem to work :

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dashboard/gems/tmail-1.2.0/lib/tmail/encode.rb:93: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@dashboard/gems/tmail-1.2.0/lib/tmail/scanner_r.rb:108: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective
```